# What is the algorithm to get the absolute URL from a string in a worker context?

Tags: javascript, url, import, web-worker

Inside a worker absolute what is the algorithm to get the absolute URL from a string when using `importScripts` ?

In my case I have a worker script generated from a Blob, where the script gets properly imported here:

```
importScripts("http://localhost:8080/http");
```

but not here:

```
importScripts("http"); // SyntaxError: Failed to load worker script at "http"
importScripts("/http"); // SyntaxError: Failed to load worker script at "/http"
```

I don't want to hard code the entire URL `http://localhost:8080/http`. Basically what I want to know is what the relative URL is going to be transformed as.

For what reasons can     `importScripts("http://localhost:8080/http");` work and not  `importScripts("http");`. The worker has been created with a Blob at runtime, does it affect  `importScripts` ?

Comment: Adding `/` before a resource will reference to home directory. You can use `/http`.

Comment: I  also  tried this